# functions in a class(C++)

Tags: c++

I learned that the functions in class must be 'inline' from a book
But, I can't understand why...
That book wasn't enough
I'm not native speaker in English, and so I'm very poor at searching in web described by Engilsh
And my country's web sites is very closed to students like me
So please answer me

I think
If a function(not inline) were in a class, the function' s stackframe (some adresses, arguments and so on) would be created repeatedly whenever compiler refer to that function
so this is why funtions in a class must be inline?
Sorry for my poor English

Comment: Member functions don't have to be inline.  As Basile's answer explains, sometimes they are marked `inline` automatically, but it is not necessary to write the member function bodies inside the class in C++ (Java programmers may find this very strange).  Also, [the C++ `inline` keyword does not actually have anything to do with the inlining optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3212635/103167).

Answer (score 1):

In the definition of C++, if a member function is declared inside the `class` it is understood by the compiler as being `inline`

Notice that `inline` (including the implicit one for functions declared *inside* `class`) is just a *hint* to the compiler, which may or may not actually [inline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) that function on some (or all or none) of its call sites. Inlining is always an optimization which the compiler is free to implement or not, and it often enables other optimizations too.

BTW, some compilers may inline functions not marked as `inline`, and that may be even done across compilation units with the so called [link-time-optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) (for `g++` compile *and* link with `-flto -O2`)